# DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, dom

Newbie question - Is this code eloquent enough to create four list items? or Should I be using documentFragment instead? The code seems to work fine - [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssosina/4t8kkpjz/4/).

Created list and li variables

```
var list = document.getElementById("myList");
var li = null;
```

Created x number of list elements and companion text nodes

```
for(var i=1; i<=4; i++){
var li = document.createElement("li");  
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Number " + i));
```

Add li to list

```
list.appendChild(li);
```

}

Comment: The jsfiddle you linked doesn't seem to have anything to do with this question. You're creating a list with a **class** "myList" but then attempting to access it by id, which won't work.

Comment: How does getting an element by ID that doesn't have one even work? In any case, what's the criteria for determining if it's "eloquent enough"?

Comment: @Pointy sorry, i've just updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is an error, because you're adding the `li`s to the `body` instead of the `ul` 
also the markup is not well created, change

```
<ul class="myList"></ul>
```

with

```
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```

To use an `id` and then:

```
var list = document.getElementById("myList");
var li = null;

for(var i=1; i<=4; i++){
   var li = document.createElement("li");  
   li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Number " + i));
   //document.body.appendChild(li); **error here**
   list.appendChild(li); //fix
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Based entirely on the JSFiddle demo you've provided: No. What you currently have is semantically incorrect. You're currently appending your `li` to the `body`, **not** the `ul` element:

```
<ul></ul>
<li>Number 1</li>
```

Change:

```
document.body.appendChild(li);
```

To:

```
list.appendChild(li);
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4t8kkpjz/1/).

---

As for the code you've provided in the question, you also need to change it so that your `li` elements get appended to your `ul` element. You also need to change your `class` into an `ID`, as `getElementById("myList")` pulls an element with an ID of "myList", whereas your current `ul` has no such ID.